# neighbor throwing debris over fence on my lawn

Tags: united-states

18 years ago, my next-door neighbor put up a chainlink fence separating our yards. They did not place the fence ON the property line, but 3-4" inward on their own land. We lived in peace for 18 years. Last year, she had a spat with my husband, and after 18 years of peace, she is now claiming that 3-4" of land over the fence, on our side, and is laying her yard waste and debris there. She shoves it through the chainlink fence. She is actually placing weeds on top of the land we've maintained for the past 18 years. As a matter of fact, we have mulch and arborvitae bushes lining the fence, so to be spiteful, she is carefully gathering weeds and placing the weeds, 4' in, down the length of OUR side of her fence. Is this legal?

We never saw any official surveyor map. We are just taking her word for it that she owns 4" on our side, but if a neighbor chooses to put up a fence on their own, can they claim the opposite side of the fence after 18 years?

Thank you!

Comment: Which state are you in? Most real estate law is handled at the state level.

Comment: Talk to a lawyer and ask whether adverse possession applies under your state's laws (different states have different rules), and consider hiring a surveyor to confirm the property line.

Comment: Editing a post to remove its content is considered vandalism on Stack Exchange; please avoid it. If there is content that should not be released publicly, you can flag for a moderator to review it, by including an explanation of the issue. If you want to delete the post, you can do this by clicking the 'delete' below your own question (and there are no applicable restrictions at this time, so it should succeed).

Comment: In the UK, if someone puts up a fence between properties, and not exactly at the border, and nobody takes action, then after some longish time (several years at least) the property on your side of the fence is yours, and the property on their side of the fence is theirs. Works either way. You should ask a competent lawyer if that is the case in your situation, in which case the neighbour might be losing a few inches of land.

Comment: On the other hand, I've read plenty of stories about neighbours who fall out for some stupid reason, and then they are both pigheaded and run to the courts and nobody wants to give in, and in the end they have a six digit bill for basically nothing. So by far the cheapest way to solve the problem is to make up and stop fighting.